# How to compile libraries with my project from their respective folders with Makefile?

Tags: makefile, libraries

what I want to do is having a Makefile that will compile every library I'm using for my program using their respective folders like this:

```
LIBDIR=lib
LIB_SUBDIRS=a b c
LIB_SUBDIRS:=$(addprefix $(LIBDIR)/, $(LIB_SUBDIRS))
LIB=libfoo.a libbar.so libbaz.dylib
# libfoo.a, libbar.so and libbaz.dylib have a makefile to compile them
# respectively in folder a, b, and c and copy the library file to the
# project's main directory

# I want a rule that will go to each directory a, b and c and execute $(MAKE)
# but only if the libraries aren't already compiled, and without knowing if it's
# .a, .so, .dylib ...
# So for this example if we run make the first time, it will do
# $(MAKE) -C lib/a
# cp lib/a/libfoo.a .
# $(MAKE) -C lib/b
# cp lib/b/libbar.so .
# $(MAKE) -C lib/c
# cp lib/c/libbaz.dylib .
# then compile my project with the libraries

# so the rule would look like this

$(word i, $(LIB)): $(word i, $(LIB_SUBDIRS))
    $(MAKE) -C $<
    cp $</$@ .
# where I want i to iterate throught the variable

# and if we run it a second time I just want the 'up to date' output
```

Comment: I don't know what the `-P` option you show here is supposed to be; there's no `-P` option for make.

Comment: @MadScientist *-C my bad

Comment: Note: You are using the term "folders" and "directories" inconsistently. Folders are a Windows concept and not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real way that you can avoid recursing into subdirectories and running make.  The parent make cannot know whether the child make has anything to do, other than by running the child make or else replicating all the rules needed to build the child make's targets... and then you've implemented a non-recursive make implementation (which is actually a good thing, but is a completely different answer).

What you need to do is ensure that the child make doesn't rebuild anything unless it's out of date.  Then the parent make invokes the child make to try to build things and if it doesn't change anything then the parent won't need to rebuild anything either.

It's really not clear from your question what exactly you want to do.  If you just want the libraries to be copied, then the simplest thing is:

```
all: $(LIB_SUBDIRS)

$(LIB_SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY: $(LIB_SUBDIRS)
```

then have each subdir makefile copy the files if they're out of date.  Then the parent doesn't need to know anything about what the child make does.

But, if the parent make needs to actually *use* those libraries for something then you'll have to list them in the parent make as prerequisites of some target: then you'll need to do something different.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, use those libraries for my bigger project

Comment: We can't really help, unless you show a minimal complete example of what you want to do, showing how you want to use these libraries.

Comment: I added some additional information to how my rule would look like, then to compile with my program it's just a simple `gcc -L.`